# java: super must be first in a constructor

Tags: java, try-catch, super

I know this has been asked before but their situation is quite different from mine.

```
class Derived extends Base {
    public Derived()
    {
        try {
           super();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is how do I get around the problem that super has to be first - I need to wrap it in a try/except block and that won't compile.

None of the earlier answers touched into problems with try/except in relation to this issue so don't tell me this question has already been answered.

Comment: Perhaps a more elaborate code example of what you are trying to accomplish might help.

Comment: Java does not allow that for a reason: if `super()` throws some Exception, the "Base" part of the object was not properly initialized, and there is no reliable way to fix that.

Comment: Maybe use the *builder-* or the *factory-pattern* where you could throw an exception *before* you try to initialize a class

Comment: What are you really trying to obtain? It sounds to me a bit like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Catch exception from super constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830004/java-catch-exception-from-super-constructor)

Answer (score 5):

You simply can't do that, make the constructor throw an exception and catch it outside.

Comment: This is a better comment than an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you can- try to use composition. Make Derived have a field of type Base (instead of extending it) and wrap a call to Base's constructor in try-catch block inside of Derived's constructor